# Wilsonian Renormalisation -- Peskin & Schroder Sect. 12.1

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, fourier-transform, path-integral

I'm working my way through Peskin & Schroeder, but some of the details of the calculations done in their introduction to the renormalisation group are slipping past me.

For concreteness, the section opens with considering the object $Z \equiv \int D\phi \exp\left(-\int d^dx \frac{1}{2} (\partial_\mu \phi)^2 + \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2 + \frac{\lambda}{4!} \phi^4\right)$, with momenta Euclidean.

It goes on to introduce some large cutoff momentum $\Lambda$ and split the integration variables integration variables $\phi(k)$ into 'low'- and 'high'-momentum modes by defining, for some $b \in (0, 1)$:
$$
\phi(k) = \begin{cases}
\phi(k) & |k| < b\Lambda \\
0 & \mbox{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\hat{\phi}(k) = \begin{cases}
\phi(k) & b\Lambda \le k < \Lambda \\
0 & \mbox{otherwise.} 
\end{cases}
$$

The substitution $\phi \mapsto \phi + \hat{\phi}$ then gets made in $Z$, to give:
$$
Z = \int D\phi D\hat{\phi}\ e^{-\int d^dx \mathcal{L}(\phi)} e^{-\int d^d x\mathcal{\hat{L}}}
$$
$$
\mathcal{\hat{L}} \equiv \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \hat{\phi})^2 + \frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2 + \lambda \left(\frac{1}{6} \phi^3 \hat{\phi} + \frac{1}{4}\phi^2 \hat{\phi}^2 + \frac{1}{6} \phi \hat{\phi}^3\right),
$$
where since $\Lambda$ is by assumption large the terms involving $m^2$ and $\lambda$ are treated as perturbations to the leading-order term $\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu)^2$ in $\mathcal{\hat{L}}$. So far, so good.

However, the next step confuses me--it goes on to state the leading term of $\mathcal{\hat{L}}$ in momentum space as $\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{d^d k}{(2\pi)^d} \hat{\phi}^*(k) k^2 \hat{\phi}(k)$, whereas I seem to lose the complex conjugate in my attempt:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} \int d^dx (\partial_\mu\hat{\phi})^2 &= \frac{1}{2} \int d^dx \frac{d^d k_1}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{d^d k_2}{(2\pi)^d} (-ik_{1, \mu})(-ik_2^\mu)\hat{\phi}(k_1) \hat{\phi}(k_2) e^{-i(k_1 + k_2)x} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{d^d k}{(2\pi)^d} \hat{\phi}(k)k^2 \hat{\phi}(-k)
\end{align}
$$

Related to this confusion is the claim immediately following that this can be associated with a propagator of the form $\frac{1}{k^2} (2\pi)^d \delta^(d) (k)$ for $k \in [b\Lambda, \Lambda)$ (and vanishing elsehwhere), and then using Wick's theorem to evaluate the $D\hat{\phi}$ integral perturbatively.

I'm struggling to see how Wick's theorem comes into play, which could be stemming from the previous issues--I've tried reading slightly further ahead in the text to see if that helped (as it has with this book in the past), but no such luck.

Would anybody be able to cast some light on these issues?

Comment: $\phi(x)$ is a real field, so $\phi(-k)=\phi(k)^*$

Comment: How embarrassing! Thanks for pointing that out. Time for a break if I'm missing something that obvious I think.

Comment: Wick's theorem is the workhorse for perturbation theory.

Comment: fs137: I understand how it applies to computing time-ordered VEVs in terms of the normal-ordered sum of all possible contractions, but applying it here is unfamiliar ground. Is it to do with the fact that functional integrals of the form $\int D_\phi \phi(x) \phi(y) e^{-S[\phi]}$ (after Wick-rotation, and possibly with additional factors in the integrand) correspond to (up to vaccuum bubble diagrams) similar VEVs?